# Hiding comments inside posts - Is it allowed?

Tags: discussion, markdown

Ok, a while ago (a few seconds after I joined SE Network first time), I saw a thing which I found particularly interesting. If I want, I can hide a comment inside a post just by placing a `<` in front of it on a newline. For example, below is something hidden as of now, but you won't be able to see it:

---

But, If you click the edit button below, and see the markdown, its here!

So, is it an intentional *feature*?

Is it against the dense SE laws to hide such comments inside posts?

Comment: There's even real syntax for comments `<!-- comment -->` which is useful in some corner cases (and for code highlighting).

Comment: Why would you want to? But sure, you **can** if you want.

Comment: @Mat Ok, I didn't know that, thanks for pointing that out... Cheers!

Comment: @Oded For the same reason geeky programmers keep whispering to themselves, or blogging on a private blog, while locked behind a screen filled of random characters, trying to solve a [coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, that's fine. It's rare, but sometimes this is actually helpful; for an example see the Markdown source of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/214543#214543).

The fact that this behaves like a comment is really just a side effect, because the HTML sanitizer will grab anything that starts with a `<` and ends with the next `>`, and if it doesn't match a white list, it will just remove it.

Even HTML comments (like `<!-- foo -->`), while being handled by the Markdown phase, will simply disappear during the sanitization phase because they're not whitelisted.

However, even though a single `<` would (mostly) behave the same way, you should use "real" HTML comments because

- it's clearer, and
- there's still *some* special handling of HTML comments in the Markdown processor.

Comment: Ohh, thats really great link... Btw, why not then remove the way I stated and just keep the one you mentioned? Its better in my view...

Comment: @AwalGarg Again, it's merely a side-effect -- you're creating invalid HTML, and we remove it. *Not* doing that isn't really an option.

Comment: Ok, thnx. Ahh yes, I know the html thing of course... I just thought, maybe SE guys have some superhuman way of sanitization...

Comment: Nope, it's very very simple. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js?r=e4b33b78d95896d282ea5632fcd83d9cba18b71b#18), lines 18 through 35 -- that's all.

Comment: @balpha: What *would* be an option would be to HTML-escape the non-whitelisted tags (turning e.g. `<foobar>` into `&lt;foobar&gt;`) instead of just stripping them, so that they'd get displayed as plain text.